# How to pass global debug flag variable throughout my code; should I use argparse?

Tags: python, logging, argparse, global, debug-mode

Let's say I have a main program (test.py) and a little utilities program (test_utils.py) that has helper functions called by the main program.
I would like to turn on debug statements in the code by passing a `debug_flag` boolean, which is read in via `argparse`.

Now I would like functions within my `test_utils.py` program to print debug statements as well, according to the value of `debug_flag`. I could always add `debug_flag` as a parameter to each function definition in `test_utils.py` and pass the parameter when the function is called, but is there a better way here, like make  `debug_flag` a global variable? But if I do declare `debug_flag` to be global from  `test.py`, how would that be imported into  `test_utils.py`?

What would be the most elegant/Pythonic approach here?

test.py:

```
import argparse
from test_utils import summation

def main():
    args = get_args()
    debug_flag = True if args[debug] == 'True' else False
    print summation(5, 6, 7)

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test program')
    parser.add_argument('-d','--debug', help='Debug True/False', default=False)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    return args
```

test_utils.py:

```
from test import debug_flag

def summation(x, y, z):
    if debug_flag:
        print 'I am going to add %s %s and %s' % (x, y, z)
    return x + y + z
```

EDIT1: To clarify - if I pass in the debug flag through argparse and thereby do set debug_flag to True - how would this be propagated to functions within `test_utils.py`?

EDIT2: Based on the suggestion by @joran-beasley, here's what I've got.

test.py:

```
import argparse
import logging
from test_utils import summation

def main():
    args = get_args()
    logging.getLogger("my_logger").setLevel(logging.DEBUG if args['debug'] == 'True' else logging.WARNING)
    print summation(5, 6, 7)

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test program')
    parser.add_argument('-d','--debug', help='Debug True/False', required=True)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    return args

main()
```

test_utils.py

```
import logging

log = logging.getLogger('my_logger')

def summation(x, y, z):
    log.debug('I am going to add %s %s and %s' % (x, y, z))
    return x + y + z
```

When I run test.py, I get:

```
$ python test.py -d True
No handlers could be found for logger "my_logger"
18
```

Comment: You might want to use `logging` : https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html

Comment: @Adonis lol your comment beat my answer by 56 seconds :P

Comment: `args[debug]` is an error. And `args.debug` already contains a boolean.

Comment: Adding `global debug_flag` to `main` would make it a module-level variable instead of a function-local variable.

Comment: I guess if you want to use that variable for more than logging, a Java kind of approach would be to store this variable inside a "config" class (which would store other configurations as well) @JoranBeasley Great minds think alike!

Comment: You can achieve a "true" multi-module global (or at least something that behaves like one) by passing an instance of a user-defined class from module to module via the import statement. This is what many projects with complex configurations (eg ['rcParams' in `matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#dynamic-rc-settings)) do. In fact, any mutable will do, so you could also just pass around a `list` or a `dict`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use logging

```
# this logger will always now be logging.DEBUG level
logging.getLogger("my_logger").setLevel(logging.DEBUG if args.debug else logging.WARNING)
```

then use

```
log = logging.getLogger("my_logger")
...
log.warn("some text that should always be seen!")
log.debug("some debug info!")
```

you can then do things where you have multiple levels of logging

```
log_level = logging.WARNING
if args.verbose > 0:
   log_level = logging.INFO
elif args.verbose > 3:
   log_level = logging.DEBUG
```

if for some reason you needed to retrieve the currentEffectiveLogLevel (you really shouldnt in most cases ... simply use `log.debug` when you want debug level output)

```
logging.getLogger("my_logger").getEffectiveLevel()
```

[edit to clarify]

```
log = logging.getLogger('my_logger')

def summation(x, y, z):
   log.debug('I am going to add %s %s and %s' % (x, y, z)) # will not print if my_logger does not have an effective level of debug
   return x + y + z

print(summation(2, 3, 4))
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
print(summation(4, 5, 6))
```

or you can wrie a helper funtion

```
def is_debug():
    return logging.getLogger("my_logger").getEffectiveLevel() == logging.DEBUG
```

of coarse you can always do some horrible hacky crap also like writing it to a flat file and reading it in or using truly global variables (harder than you might think and lots of edge cases to worry about)

Comment: But the `args.debug` parm is read in from `test.py` which imports `test_utils.py` - I'm looking for a way for functions within `test_utils.py` to be able to use `args.debug`

Comment: you set the log level based on that ... you then output to the appropriate log channel automagically... you can also get the logs level from anywhere and use that to determine if the flag was passed in ...

Comment: But this appears to work only if I set the logging in program A and call summation from within that program. Could you check my EDIT2? I've added what I'm running now

Comment: @Craig just add `logging.basicConfig()` at the top of main.py ... see https://repl.it/repls/TestyGruesomeNumbers

Answer (score 1):

You can acheive a "package-wide" global in Python by passing around a mutable. My favored approach in these situations is to create a custom `Flags` class. You then share an instance of `Flags` between all of your modules, and its attributes function like globals. Here's an example in terms of the code you posted:

test_utils.py

```
__all__ = ['flags', 'summation']

class Flags(object):
    def __init__(self, *items):
        for key,val in zip(items[:-1], items[1:]):
            setattr(self,key,val)

flags = Flags('debug', False)

def summation(x, y, z):
    if flags.debug:
        print 'I am going to add %s %s and %s' % (x, y, z)
    return x + y + z
```

test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import argparse
import sys

from test_utils import summation, flags

def main():
    args = get_args()
    flags.debug = args['debug']
    print summation(5, 6, 7)

def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test program')
    parser.add_argument('-d','--debug', action='store_true', help='Debug True/False', default=False)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    return args

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

I moved flags to test_utils.py to avoid a circular import issue, but that shouldn't affect anything. A more robust solution (appropriate for larger projects) would be to have a separate config.py (or something) module in which `flags` is initialized.

Comment: But the problem is that I want functions in `test_utils` to use the `debug_flag`

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer. Assign a dict in the main file.  Then import it via all the other modules.

Test.py

```
debug_flag = {'setting' : False}
```

test_utils.py

```
from test import debug_flag

def print_flag():
    print(debug_flag['setting'])

def set_flag(setting):
    debug_flag['setting'] = setting

set_flag(True)
print_flag()
```

Now anytime you import the debug_flag from the main module, it will have whatever setting you set the flag too once you processed the arg parse.  You could then change this at anytime, and subsequent calls will pick up the change.

Comment: You have a syntax error (should be `from test import debug_flag`) and a more serious semantic error. Since the OP is also importing `summation` from test_utils.py in test.py, the way you currently have the imports organized will raise an `ImportError` due to the circular imports.

Comment: I was just showing a use case, the way he has his imports is irrelevant, his code was unusable to begin with.   args[debug] makes no sense.  His code is going to have to be rewritten regardless.